# Upload and download Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, file-upload, download

I need to create a knowledge bank portal where user with permission can upload and also download the document such pdf,docx. The other user such as public can use search to search document and download. I made it from scratch and it almost done but suddenly I need to use the Joomla to create the portal. I'm still new in using Joomla. Is it possible to have the upload/download function in joomla??I want the function same with the example below.

user with permission can upload the document and it will display at the table and then the user can download it.

[image]

It's same to other page. User with permission can upload the document and it will display at the table and then the user can download it.

[image]

The difference is the document will show in the table at the page where the document uploaded. Then, public or guest use search to search the document and download. Can someone help me!!!

Comment: This question risks being Too Broad.  How far have you managed to code before your progress was halted?  May we see your efforts?

Comment: The example above I made it from scratch just using the php. The upload/download and search all work well. I just don't know how to implement the same function by using the Joomla. Right now, I try made the user with permission create the article then attach the document then publish the article. Is it the correct way? or any other way that I can use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this would probably be to install a download extension.

It looks like [jDownloads](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jdownloads) will do what you need and it's free:

> "Access Rights for Categories: You can set the 'download' rights for categories and downloads for every Joomla user group. So it is possible, for example, that all guests can view the category (and the files) but only registered users can download the files. And say users with Publisher or similar rights can create new Downloads including uploading the main download file, together with preview text, images, audio clips (MP3) and video clips (MP4)."

There are likely others in the [Joomla Extensions Directory](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension).